# Start simple Go/Golang server with systemd on Debian or Ubuntu

Tags: systemd

I want to start the following Golang code with systemd:

```
...

func main() {
  // main routes
  http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
  log.Fatalln(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello")
}
```

The code is built with `go build`

Name of resulting binary: MyApp

Path: `/home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp` - the second `MyApp` is the binary file

Inside `/lib/systemd/system` I place the file `MyApp.service` with the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp service
After=network.target

[Socket]
ListenStream=80
NoDelay=true

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
User=andrei
Group=andrei

WorkingDirectory=/home/andrei/MyApp
ExecStart=/home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On Ubuntu I run the command (with sudo on Debian):

```
sistemctl start MyApp.service
sistemctl status MyApp.service
```

I get the output:

```
● MyApp.service - MyApp service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/MyApp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-11-14 11:30:45 UTC; 1s ago
Process: 14883 ExecStart=/home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 14883 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 14 11:30:45 andrei systemd[1]: MyApp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 14 11:30:45 andrei systemd[1]: MyApp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`NOTE:`

When I run the app from the terminal everything works fine.

How can I start the app with systemd?

`Update:`

It works by doing the following:

`sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp`

A better unit file is helpful - not required to make it work:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=andrei
Group=andrei
WorkingDirectory=/home/andrei/MyApp
ExecStart=/home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp

# make sure log directory exists and owned by syslog
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/sleepservice
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown syslog:adm /var/log/sleepservice
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 /var/log/sleepservice
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=sleepservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And now make it work with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start MyApp.service
sudo systemctl enable MyApp.service # app will start on OS restart
sudo journalctl -f -u MyApp.service # provide information about the app
```

Comment: Can you add `journalctl` logs when you try to start it?

Comment: @raspi `journalctl` was helpful to understand that I have a permission problem on port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you're running your application with a non-root user (`User=andrei`) but then your application is trying to listen on port 80 (`http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)`), which is a privileged port that normally only root can listen on.

When you say:

> When I run the app from the terminal everything works fine.

By any chance, are you running it as *root*? Because then, I'd expect it to work fine.

If you're OK with using a different port (port number above 1024, which would be unprivileged), then that would be the easiest solution to have your service run as non-root.

---

Also, this snippet from your unit file:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=80
NoDelay=true
```

This doesn't really work on a service unit, it only works on a [socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html), so to make [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) work you'd need a separate `MyApp.socket` unit with those settings.

But socket activation is more complex than just creating a separate unit, since the application itself needs support to receive the listening socket from systemd. For example, a C application would call [sd_listend_fds()](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_listen_fds.html) and link to libsystemd to implement this. There might be bindings to do the same in Go, look for [coreos/go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd) for example, there might be some there.

Socket activation would have the advantage that you would be able to use port 80 and a non-root user, but as mentioned, needs changes to your application.

Comment: You are right @Filipe Brandenburger.
Thank you for the help.

To make it work I give to `MyApp` the ability to run on lower ports with the command:
 `sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp`

This solution is taken from:  [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443).

Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: @Gopher systemd can manage the capabilities for you. I believe all you need is `CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` and change your command in `ExecStart=` to use a `!!` prefix, in your case `ExecStart=!!/home/andrei/MyApp/MyApp`. With those settings, systemd will run your service with the non-root user but increased capabilities to allow it to bind to port 80. This is from memory, so might not be 100% accurate, if you google for it you might find a more complete recipe. Cheers!